# Does the given sentence mean how I interpreted it?

Tags: sentence-meaning

He yelled at me for the mistakes I had made, coming back home.

Does the above sentence mean **He came back home and yelled at me for the mistakes I (had) made?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might do. Or it might refer to the mistakes I had made when I was coming back home, or the mistakes I made in coming back home at all. It is genuinely ambiguous.

Comment: "Coming back home" would be a single mistake, and so would usually be phrased "... **mistake** I had made **in** coming back home".  But I agree it's completely unclear who is coming home, and when and where the mistakes occurred.